# Mercurial - Merging changes between forks

Tags: merge, mercurial, repository, tortoisehg

I'm running into a problem trying to merge changes from a parent into the fork I'm working on. Here's a more thorough description:

There's repository A. I started repository B as a fork of repository A. B is a wholey different application to A, but shares a lot of internal back-end functionality, so one thing that is crucial is being able to apply certain common updates and bug-fixes that are common to both applications.

So B is a couple of months into development, parallel to A, when things are stable enough that I decided to start pulling changes into it from A. I add A as a remote repository, and pull and merge various commits from A's main branch into B.

So far everything is fine. The application B now runs with all of the updated features I wanted from A.

I commit these updates to B locally. The problem comes when I try to push the update. Hg Workbench informs me that it's aborting, because "push creates new remote branches". The branches that it lists are old development branches of A. They've been merged into A and closed over the course of A's development.

What looks like is happening is that when I try to push this updated version of B, it's trying to recreate all of these old A branches in B's repository, which I definitely don't want to do.

Did I go about this wrong? How am I supposed to pull changes from A into B, and then push changes to B without mangling B in the process?

Answer (score 0):

You probably pulled *everything* from the repository A into your repository B. Now, when you push to B, it will want to push everything you now have to your remote copy of B, including all heads which you pulled from A.

You can push only a certain revision, including ALL of its ancestors via
`hg push -rXXX` where `XXX` is the revision you want to push. Or you can push a certain branch.

However: when you merged from anoter brach you imported from A, you NEED to push that branch, too, as it is part of the ancestors of your new changeset, thus you might need to resort to using `hg push --force` no matter what, as you might have a new branch - depending on what you merged.

You will not need to push completely unrelated changesets, though.

Comment: So all I really care about is A/default, but I'm getting a ton of A/feature/#### branches, which are ancestors to A/default. Does this mean that I can't avoid adding all of the A/feature/#### branches to my repo?

Comment: What if f I started again from scratch, but make it a point to only pull changes specifically from A/default?

Comment: Every changeset which is a direct ancestor of your merge changeset needs to be part of the history as it directly contributes to the current state. Thus, if the history of A/default contains several merges from A/feature/#### then those need to be part of the history.